# Accessing dynamic 2D char array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, dynamic, multidimensional-array

In my class I've got:

```
private:
    //...
    char** mNumber;
//...
```

Then I initialize it in constructor:

```
PhoneBook::PhoneBook()
{   
    mNumber = NULL;

}
```

I also have method set default:

```
bool PhoneBook::setDefault()
{
    lock();
    //...

    for (uint8 i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        mNumber[i] = new char[5];
        for (uint8 k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
        {
            mNumber[i][k] = '0' + k;
        }
        mNumber[i][4] = '\0';
    }
    unlock();
    return true;
}
```

In my program, when I want to write number (I can write up to five numbers), program should use method:

```
    bool PhoneBook::write(DataOutputStream& s)

{
    lock();
    //...
    unsigned long checksum = 0;

    for (uint8 j = 0; j <5; j++)
    {
        unsigned short k = 0;
        do
        {
        char number= mUserNo[j][k];
        checksum += 0x000000FF & (number>> 8); //checksum is not problem here I guess
        checksum += 0x000000FF & (number);
        s.write_int8(userNo);
        } while(mNumber[j][k++]=='\0');
    }

    s.write_uint32(checksum);
    s.flush();
    unlock();
    return (s.ok());
}
```

It crashes at line:

```
char userNo = mUserNo[j][k];
```

It also do not set default values (they are not displayed in application window where they are supposed to be).
Visual Studio 2010 prompt:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x012b6fb8 (main_app.exe) in main_app: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xfdfdcdcd.
```

I've tried to debug it, but can't find out what's wrong. I can only guess that it's something wrong with 2d array, since I feel not so good with them and when I've tried something similiar with 1D, it worked fine.
Please help me with code and let better understand multiD arrays in c++.
BTW I'm not allowe to use std::string. Just no, I can't use it here.

Comment: Um. did you intend `mNumber[j][k++]=='\0'` in your while-loop condition to be `!=` instead, because as near as I can see that will fail on the first element. Second, 0xfdfdcdcd indicates you're accessing part of a boundary page and part of a freed page, which means you had better check *all* your index logic. Also, you setup `mNumber` in `setDefault()`, but use  `mUserNo` in `write()`. They're different names. Either that is part of your problem, or you need to post **real** code.

Comment: I really suggest to use `std::vector` (or `char mNumber[5][5]` if really you don't be allowed to use it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you need "char**" instead std::vector, you should to allocate memory for it before filling default values. Like this,

```
bool PhoneBook::setDefault()
{
........
mNumber = new char*[5];           // allocating memory for mNumber
for (uint8 i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
{
    mNumber[i] = new char[4];
    for (uint8 k = 0; k < 4; ++k)
    {
        mNumber[i][k] = '0' + k;
    }
    mNumber[i][4] = '\0';
}
unlock();
return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You only ever set mNumber to NULL so any access to memory via mNumber, mNumber [j][k] for example, is most likely going to crash with an access violation (1). You need to initialise mNumber to be a meaningful value, by using `new` somewhere! Better still, use a standard container like `std::vector`:

```
// the declaration of mNumber, do not initialise mNumber to NULL!
std::vector <char *> mNumber; // only need one * here!
```

(1) This is the most common thing to happen on Windows and Linux, some (but not many) OSes/systems may silently let you do this!